# Why does std::atomic_thread_fence have "C" linkage?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I have no guess as to why it would be desirable for this function to have "C" rather than "C++" linkage.

Comment: Could it be because the same function exists in `C` http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_thread_fence and this is just the imported (into the std namespace) version?

Answer (score 5):

That was added by [LWG issue 1479](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#1479) which was addressing a last-minute comment on C++11.

The rationale for this change was C language compatibility (C11 thread library has identically-named function [atomic_thread_fence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) in stdatomic.h).

As far as I understand, it was always a plan that C and C++ atomic libraries can coexist: other examples of compatiblity are the C-compatible type aliases for std::atomic, such as `atomic_int` and the C-compatibility macro [ATOMIC_VAR_INIT](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/ATOMIC_VAR_INIT)

Comment: I don't understand how the C and C++ prototypes are compatible, given that the C++ prototype is in the std namespace.

Comment: @WaltK I would guess it allows the C++ implementation of `<atomic>` to include `<stdatomic.h>` and then say `namespace std { using ::atomic_thread_fence; }` or something equivalent. Of course it doesn't help `atomic_flag_test_and_set` which still has C++ linkage in C++ - perhaps that NB comment wasn't  thought out that well.

Comment: @WaltK exactly like `sin` or `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

`atomic_thread_fence` establishes memory synchronization ordering of non-atomic and relaxed atomic accesses.
Concurrency, especially relaxed-memory concurrency, is a notoriously
subtle and error-prone domain, and so verifying such optimisations
is of great interest. [Ref1](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/CompCertTSO/doc/fenceelim.pdf).
For such thing is widely used [CompCertTSO](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/CompCertTSO/doc/).
CompCertTSO is a compiler that generates x86 assembly code from ClightTSO, a large subset of the C programming language enhanced with concurrency primitives for thread management and synchronisation, and with a TSO relaxed memory model based on the x86-TSO model.

So, for verification, optimisation and testing purposes is desirable for this function to have "C" linkage.